# Weird issue on Safari after updating ReactJS libraries: Alternatives to deprecated polyfills

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, babel-polyfill

I recently updated some of my libraries in ReactJS and now I seem to be experiencing a very weird issue on some versions of Safari. I read somewhere this could be resolved using polyfill, but I checked and their library is now deprecated. Are there any alternatives or quick fixes for this?

[image]

Comment: `Array#at()` is being supported since Safari 15.4 [source](https://caniuse.com/?search=Array.at). Which versions are you looking at? *What* library has been deprecated? Look into [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) which has a vast collection of polyfills (including `Array#at()`) for you to include in your project